# Data Binding - communicating between 2 custom elements within another custom element

Tags: polymer, web-component

my-app is a custom element which contains two other custom elements that need to communicate with each other. When i click a button on the the header element I want the drawer element to open/close. I am trying to use data-binding for messaging but i am unable to get it to work.

I think I might have to use iron-signals for this but I would like to know why data-binding does not work in this condition.

**Parent Element - my-app**

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
        <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>
            <my-header drawer-active="{{drawerState}}"></my-header>
            <div id="main-content" class="">
                <div class="imgWrap"><img src="../images/banner.jpg"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
            <my-drawer drawer-opened="{{drawerState}}"></my-drawer>
        </app-header-layout>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-app',
        properties: {
            drawerState: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false,
                notify: true
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Child Element - my-header**

```
<dom-module id="my-header">
    <template>
        <app-header>
            <app-toolbar>
                <div class="logo"><img src="../images/logo.svg"></img>
                </div>
                <paper-icon-button icon="menu" on-tap="toggleDrawer"></paper-icon-button>
            </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-header',
        properties: {
            drawerActive: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false,
                notify: true
            }
        },
        toggleDrawer: function() {

            this.drawerActive = !this.drawerActive;
        }
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

**Child Element - my-drawer**

```
<dom-module id="my-drawer">
    <template>
        <app-drawer align="end" opened="{{drawerOpened}}">
            <paper-menu> ... </paper-menu>
        </app-drawer>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-drawer',

        properties: {
            drawerOpened: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: false,
                notify: true
            }
        }

    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: It works fine for me just copying and pasting. Are you sure you have `app-layout` loaded?

Comment: @miyamoto I double-checked my imports and import my-drawer was missing in my-app. I could have sworn that i had added it. Thank you so much and terribly sorry for your trouble. Should I delete this Question?

Comment: Up to you. I will say a couple more things, I anticipate problems for you with your elements as they're currently structured. I would advise moving the `app-header` and `app-drawer` elements from `my-header` and `my-drawer` to your `my-app` element and use `my-header` and `my-drawer` as the content children of those elements.  This keeps all the elements defining the layout of the page in one place, and I believe it's necessary for `app-header-layout` to work properly.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That makes more logical sense! I appreciate. Thank-you so much for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved. There was an import error on my part. See comments on the question.